# How to make a general callback for a button matrix with GTK+2.0

Tags: c, optimization, gtk, gtk2

Trying to code a little game with GTK+2.0, i had a weird situation where i can't chose what is the best thing to do.

My board game is a matrix filled with buttons. There are W buttons in each line and H buttons in each column.

Basicly,

> I create a table with `gtk_table_new(H, W, FALSE)`.
>
> I fill each "case" of this table with a button.

But when i want to link each button with a same `G_CALLBACK` function i'm annoyed. I have to know the button position to differentiate one of the other. But what is the best practice ?

Example:

```
===PART OF A FUNCTION===
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < H; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < W; j++)
          //Create button[i][j]
          //Table attach button[i][j] with (i, j) coordinates
          g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button[i][j]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(signal_but), data);
===END===

void signal_but(GtkWidget *but, gpointer data)
{
   //How can i know which button i'm manipulating
}
```

I think using a global array which contains coordinates of each button works. But isn't there a gtk function or an other trick to solve this problem ?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: The button class  has a tag field?

Comment: I mean, you know the button instance from 'but' yes?  You just want the [x,y] back from it, yes?

Comment: Yes :) One (x, y) for each button

Comment: IIRC, the tag is called 'user-data' and it's inherited from way up, maybe Object.  Unfortunately, it's a pointer and so you might want to consider some ugly casting:)    When you create the button, make a unique int by (i*h)+j.  Cast to pointer, shove in 'user-data'.  In the handler, get 'user-data' back from the 'but' parameter and use div, or / and %, to get the [x,y] back again:)

Comment: Ok thank you, i didn't think to this method. Ugly but perfect in my case xD

Comment: The alternative is messy allocating stuff just to transfer an integer and IME that's even uglier than the casting:)

Comment: Theres nothing that messy about allocating a struct with x and y fields: it's definitely more readable and with g_object_set_data_full() there's no need to need to free it manually.

Comment: @jku tomayto, tomahto.. :)

Comment: `GINT_TO_POINTER` and `GPOINTER_TO_INT` are just made for that "pass an int instead of a pointer" hack. Give a look at https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html